# My Activity Launches Twice

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have listview with `setOnItemClickListener()` method, when clicked I want it to open new activity and give it 2 extras, the number of the item and the user that logged in (back in home screen), the problem is that the activity starts twice, one with good extras and one with "0" in the position extra...

this code is supposed to check if Firebase server has place in it (no more than 5 players) and if so add the user to the server and join the room (launch `ServerActivity`).

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            myRef = database.getReference("Servers/S"+position);
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (dataSnapshot.child("player"+i).child("username").getValue() != null)
                        i++;
                    if (i < 5) {
                        Log.d("Implementing Child","player"+i);
                        CustomUser customUser = new CustomUser(false,currentUser.getUsername(),"",0,currentUser.getWins());
                        myRef.child("player" + i).setValue(customUser);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,ServerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("serverNum",position);
                    intent.putExtra("currentUser",currentUser);
                    Log.d("position", position + "");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Full", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        myRef.child("isJoinable").setValue(false);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +
                            "Internet Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,ServerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("currentUser",currentUser);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            //TODO FIX: activity probebly launches twice
        }
    });
```

I tried modifing `LaunchMode` in the manifest but it resulted with fail causing the "serverNum" extra to be 0 instead of the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have you added this code :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,ServerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("currentUser",currentUser);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

This would cause your `ServerActivity` to launch as soon as the listener is added. Have you tried commenting this code and use only the code in `onDataChange`?

Comment: That worked, probebly copied this code and forgot to remove it from there, was looking for this for hours now, im feeling kind of stupid right now but thanks!

Comment: @NetanelMalichi This is exactly the kind of situation where the Android Studio debugger is very useful. I strongly encourage you to learn how to use it.